# Trying to add my app to the Shortcuts app for Siri

Tags: swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts, appintents

I am developing an Ionic/Vue app with Siri shortcuts. I want the app's Siri shortcuts to automatically appear in the Shortcuts app, similar to the way the native ChatGPT app does it. I am using the `capacitor-plugin-siri-shortcuts` plugin (https://github.com/lovetodream/capacitor-plugin-siri-shortcuts) to achieve this.

So far, I am able to create shortcuts by donating and presenting the shortcut. However, this requires the user to accept a dialog. I would like my app's shortcuts to appear automatically, just like the ChatGPT app's shortcuts.

Apparently this is called "App Intents" now. I think Apple supports migrating Siri intents to App intents via `CustomIntentMigratedAppIntent`. Here is what I have done so far:

I have added the Siri capability and added the following lines to my `Info.plist` file:

```xml
<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
    <array>
      <string>com.umbrella.vet.shortcut</string>
      <string>AskUmbrellaIntent</string>
    </array>
```

I am also calling `donate` on mount:

```js
await SiriShortcuts.donate({
  persistentIdentifier: 'com.umbrella.vet.shortcut',
  title: 'Ask Umbrella Intent',
  suggestedInvocationPhrase: 'Ask Umbrella',
  isEligibleForSearch: true,
  isEligibleForPrediction: true,
})
```

I have a folder called `Intents` with one intent named `AskUmbrellaIntent`, and an `Intents.intentdefinition` file.

What am I missing?